# C++ Defining a specific object type when extending a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, extending

I have written a short template list class defining some methods I would like to use in implementations of it. My current problem is that I am having trouble extending the generic template type and defining a specific type.

In other words, assume I have a class called `MyType`

List.h:

```
template<class T>
class List
{
    public:
        Node<T> *head;
        Node<T> *tail;

 ...
}
```

Inside the `Node` class:

```
public:
    virtual T getData();
```

I want to extend this class with a specific defined type `MyType` so that I can have getData() behave differently in the extended class `MyTypeList`. I am having trouble with syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class MyTypeList : public List<T>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Did you want `MyListType` to be a template type as well?

Comment: You can have more than one template parameter `template<class T, class R>`. Is that what you mean>?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to define the type T to be MyType when using MyTypeList. This way, I could have getData manipulate the MyType object.

Comment: First, you can start with defining getData() correctly (it should return a reference, otherwise all your manipulating is a copy of the object managed in the list). Secondly, you're effectively asking to specialize the node-wrapper the list uses to manage the templates-type `T`. *Why* you want to do this (a use-case) is entirely unclear in the delivery of your question, and is likely the reason for the disconnect between what you're asking and what people are hearing. So perhaps a concrete example of usage is in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
struct MyTypeList : List<MyType> {
};
```

although it is about the same as doing:

```
typedef List<MyType> MyTypeList;
```

Comment: clever, but I'm not sure it will solve my problem. I want to be able to DEFINE the type T = MyType so that when using MyTypeList the user is required to provide objects of type MyType... That way, I could override the getData() method and have it manipulate the MyType object...

Comment: @turkycat: That is basically what it is doing.  `T` in the context of the `List` will be `MyType`.  Maybe you could provide some examples of how `MyTypeList` would be used that would make the problem clearer.

Comment: I'm sorry my intention is not more clear. Maybe this will help:
Lets say that MyType has a `.process()` method... I want to be able to override getData() in the class `MyTypeList` so that I can have getData() manipulate the MyType object. I wouldn't be able to envoke a method on a wildcard type! Using my example, I could override getData() to have it `return data.process();` rather than `return data;`

Comment: @turkycat: Maybe you are talking about a specialization so that `Node<MyType>` is defined differently from `Node`s of other types.